# Compress a picture

Tags: java, android-studio, bitmap

In my application there is a button to "upload a picture": taking a photo from camera or choosing from gallery.

On both options, there are 3 problems:

1) When clicking again to upload another picture - the application crushes

2) On the first "upload", the picture is rotated on the side (90 degrees counterclockwise)

3) The picture's size is the original size and I want it to be compressed to resolution of 125x125.

Please help (even if you have a solution to one problem)

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import entities.Order;


public class SellABookFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView ivBookPicture;
    private EditText etBookName, etBookAuthor, etBookGenre, etBookPublishing, etQuantity, etBookPrice, etBookDetails;
    private Button bUploadPicture, bAddBook;

    public SellABookFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sell_a_book, container, false);
        ivBookPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBook_Picture);
        etBookName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etBook_Name);
        etBookAuthor = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAuthor_Name);
        etBookGenre = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etGenre);
        etBookPublishing = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPublishing_Year);
        etQuantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etBook_Quantity);
        etBookPrice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etBook_Price);
        etBookDetails = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etBook_Details);
        bUploadPicture = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bUpload_Picture);
        bAddBook = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bAdd_Book);

        bUploadPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        bAddBook.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bUpload_Picture:
                selectPicture();
                break;
            case R.id.bAdd_Book:
                addBook();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void addBook() {
        try {
            HomeActivity.backEnd.addOrder(new Order(HomeActivity.LoggedUser.getID(),
                    etBookGenre.getText().toString(),
                    etBookName.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(etBookPublishing.getText().toString()),
                    etBookAuthor.getText().toString(),
                    Double.parseDouble(etBookPrice.getText().toString()),
                    (Integer) ivBookPicture.getTag()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void selectPicture() {
        final CharSequence[] options = {
                getResources().getString(R.string.take_photo),
                getResources().getString(R.string.gallery_choose),
                getResources().getString(R.string.cancel)};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.upload_picture));
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals(getResources().getString(R.string.take_photo))) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals(getResources().getString(R.string.gallery_choose))) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                } else
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        OutputStream outFile;
        String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator
                + "MyApp";
        File file;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                ivBookPicture.setImageBitmap(null);
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = null;
            }
            try {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                    for (File tmp : f.listFiles()) {
                        if (tmp.getName().equals("tmp.jpg")) {
                            f = tmp;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                    ivBookPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    if (f.delete()) {
                        file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                        try {
                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    bitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    Log.w("image path", picturePath);
                    ivBookPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ImageView which contains the uploaded picture:

```js
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBook_Picture"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/sell_a_book_picture_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sell_a_book_picture_size"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: For your first question,I think you should post your Logcat message here so we can help you find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public Bitmap compressBySize(String pathName, int targetWidth,  
            int targetHeight) {  
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);    
        int imgWidth = opts.outWidth;  
        int imgHeight = opts.outHeight;  
        int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(imgWidth / (float) targetWidth);  
        int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(imgHeight / (float) targetHeight);  
        if (widthRatio > 1 || heightRatio > 1) {  
            if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {  
                opts.inSampleSize = widthRatio;  
            } else {  
                opts.inSampleSize = heightRatio;  
            }  
        }  

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;  
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);  
        return bitmap;  
    }
```

Use this method to do the compress,just set the **targetWidth&targetHeight** yourself.

Also,you can use `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressRate, byteOutputStream);` to compress your bitmap by quality.

For the crash,it's because the picture bitmap takes too much memory.You should compress the picture and remember to release the memory after your first upload.You can consider using a **WeakReference**.

Comment: OK. I'll try it. What about the other questions?

Comment: @Nick I have commented about the first,and I have no idea about the second.But I think it's also easy to solve.If you want our help,you should post more code and logcat message.